# Does Mail throttling exist in Pardot?

Tags: pardot, send-throttling

A problem that we have run into is that organizations flag email if there are a number of them going into the company at the same time. They get flagged as bulk and are not allowed through. These people signed up, but cannot get the email. As soon as the mail is blocked, the status of the prospects is also automatically set to opt out.

Is there a send-throttling feature in Pardot?

Comment: Out of the box - new in Spring 22: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_pardot_einstein_engagement_frequency.htm&type=5&release=236 . Do it yourself: adjust the score on the prospect and have all of your send routines look at the score. If score > or < than some arbitrary threshold, then throttle. Definition of routine and how to throttle would depend on how you send. Custom everything.

Comment: In general, Pardot does not and will not support throttling: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdc2nUAB/allow-email-throttling-let-users-throttle-volume-of-emails